# Why isn't this countdown working in my node.js discord bot?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, replit

I am trying to implement some code that will start a countdown in discord. I currently have it running into the console, but it doesn't work. I have managed to get it working in a separate file, and i have copied all of the correct bits across, but it won't work. The code is on line 59. If it helps you, the code is [here](https://repl.it/@DomLowe/ONUW-Discord-Bot).

I have tried searching around on Google, and have found the same code that I'm using (I'm pretty sure). So I'm not sure why it isn't working.

I am making a One Night Ultimate Werewolf bot. One Night Ultimate Werewolf is a hidden role game, when someone if the werewolf, and has to avoid being killed. At the end, you have 2 and a half minutes to tell players your role, and try to trick them into killing/not killing you (depending on your role).

What I tried to do is make that 2 and a half minute countdown, so I expected it to run certain code, wait 3 seconds, then do other code. I would later change this code to be a 2:30 timer, so if you could tell me how to do that, that would be even better. But, at the very least, I would like to know why the code below doesn't work, and how to fix it.

The code snippet is

```
      client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        if (message.content === prefix + 'countdown') {
          console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
            }, 3000);
        }
        })
```

and the full file is

```
//required libraries
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

//What to do when the bot starts up.
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("with my ding-a-ling")
});

//prefix
var prefix = ("~")

//Find the latancy and API latency.
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'ping') {
    message.channel.send(":ping_pong: Pinging...").then((ping) => { ping.edit(`:ping_pong: Pong!\nLatency is ${Math.floor(ping.createdAt - message.createdAt)}\nAPI latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`); });
  }
}
);


client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'newgame') {
    if (message.member.roles.has("641725420957335562")) {
      client.channels.get('642070729805791232').send("Sending out message....").then((newgame) => { newgame.edit(`Hey, <@&641727807663374345>! A new game is starting. Do ~ready to apply`) })
    }

    client.on('message', message => {
      if (message.author.bot) return;

      if (message.content !== prefix + 'ready') {
        return;
      }

      if (message.content === prefix + 'ready') {
        message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}> is ready!`)
        var roles = Array("Doppelganger", "Werewolf", "Minion", "Mason", "Seer", "Robber", "Troublemaker", "Drunk", "Insomniac", "Villager", "Tanner", "Hunter")
        var role = roles[Math.floor(Math.random() * roles.length)];
      }
      message.author.send("Your role is..." + role + "!")


      client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        if (message.content === prefix + 'accept') {
          if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
            client.channels.get('642090245122293771').send(`<@${message.author.id}> has accepted their role!`)
          }
        }
      });

      client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        if (message.content === prefix + 'countdown') {
          console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
            }, 3000);
        }
        })
      });
    }
  });


//logs messages into console
client.on("message", async message => {
  console.log(`${message.author.username} said: ${message.content}`);
});

//Test command if we need it
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'test') {
    message.channel.send("test reply")
  }
}
);
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I didn't get any error, the code just didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you wanted to do. Could you give more details on the expected result?

Comment: Sure, @Androz2091. I am making a OWUW bot. OWUW is a hidden role game, when someone if the werewolf, and has to avoid being killed. At the end, you have 2:30 mins to tell players your role, and try to trick them into killing/not killing you.

What I tried to do is make that 2 and a half minute countdown, so I expected it to run certain code, wait 3 seconds, then do other code. I would later change this code to be a 2:30 timer, so if you could tell me how to do that, that would be even better. But, at the very least, I would like to know why the code below doesn't work, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not correctly nested. You are only supposed to have one client.on('message'):

```js
//required libraries
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var sleep = require('sleep');

//What to do when the bot starts up.
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("with my ding-a-ling")
});

//prefix
var prefix = ("~")

//Find the latancy and API latency.
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'ping') {
    message.channel.send(":ping_pong: Pinging...").then((ping) => { ping.edit(`:ping_pong: Pong!\nLatency is ${Math.floor(ping.createdAt - message.createdAt)}\nAPI latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`); });
  }

  if (message.content === prefix + 'newgame') {
    if (message.member.roles.has("641725420957335562")) {
      client.channels.get('642070729805791232').send("Sending out message....").then((newgame) => { newgame.edit(`Hey, <@&641727807663374345>! A new game is starting. Do ~ready to apply`) })
    }

    if (message.content === prefix + 'ready') {
        message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}> is ready!`)
        var roles = Array("Doppelganger", "Werewolf", "Minion", "Mason", "Seer", "Robber", "Troublemaker", "Drunk", "Insomniac", "Villager", "Tanner", "Hunter")
        var role = roles[Math.floor(Math.random() * roles.length)];
        message.author.send("Your role is..." + role + "!");
    }

    if (message.content === prefix + 'accept') {
       if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
         client.channels.get('642090245122293771').send(`<@${message.author.id}> has accepted their role!`)
       }
    }

    if (message.content === prefix + 'countdown') {
      console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
       }, 3000);
    }

    if (message.content === prefix + 'test') {
      message.channel.send("test reply")
    }

});


//logs messages into console
client.on("message", async message => {
  console.log(`${message.author.username} said: ${message.content}`);
});


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

This will have the same behaviour but you will have better performances and your code is more readable.

Here is an example of counter:

```js
if (message.content === prefix + 'countdown') {
  console.log('Countdown started');
  let total = Date.now() + (60000*2+60000/2); // 2 minutes later
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log((total-Date.now()/1000)+' seconds remaining');
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, (60000*2+60000/2));
  console.log("Timer ended");
}
```

It will display "x seconds remaining" every 3 seconds until the timer ends.